# Reference request for a proof of a basic version of normalization lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading some notes on affine algebraic geometry and came across the following fact:

> If $k$ is a field with $\mathrm{char}~k = 0$, then if $V(f)$ is an irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbf{A}^n_k$, then there is a surjective linear projection $\pi: \mathbf{A}^n_k \to \mathbf{A}^{n-1}_k$ such that the composition $V(f) \to \mathbf{A}^n_k \to \mathbf{A}^{n-1}_k$ is finite.

Can someone point me to resource (book/lecture notes) where I can find this statement proved?

Comment: I think you are asking about the [Noether's normalization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma) (geometric version). This is an standard fact, thus you can find it easily in algebra (e.g. Atiyah-MacDonald) or algebraic geometry textbooks (e.g. Shafarevich). I hope it helps. Since this is a particular case of a general and important theorem, I think it's worth trying a proof by yourself.